# How do I get just the Nth row of data from sybase?

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a table with multiple rows for each user. Each user will have the same number of rows but the row ids are all different for each user, so how I do get just the Nth row for a given user?

Assuming an order by user_id, row_id clause so you can be guaranteed a consistent order for any given user.

This is sybase 12 I'm working with here.

Comment: Relational databases do not have the concept of native order. Asking for the n'th item in a table is an invalid question, instead you must always ask for your data with an 'order by' clause, which I don't think is what you are specifying here.

Comment: I will update the question ...

Comment: @Cruachan: that is wrong, see my answer

Comment: @vol7ron: What @cruashan said is perfectly true - without an order by clause, you cannot be sure of what order the rows will be returned in.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Sybase SQL Anywhere (it's not clear whether you're using SA or ASE), look up the `start at` and `top` clauses of the `select` statement [here](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1200/en/dbreference/select-statement.html*d5e57230). For example:

```
select top 1 start at 7 * from mytable order by user_id, row_id
```

will retrieve the 7th row.

Answer (score 1):

SYBASE should have windowing functions

```
SELECT * 
FROM   ( select row_number() over (order by user_id, row_id) as row, bar.*
         from   bar
       ) foo
WHERE  foo.row = 7
```

- [Sybase Analytical Functions](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/BCGEEBHA.htm)
- [Sybase Window Aggregate Functions](http://iablog.sybase.com/paulley/2009/03/window-aggregate-functions/)

Comment: That's for sybase anywhere, not Sybase ASE, the answer doesn't apply to the question, unfortunately. OLAP functions are not supported in ASE.

Comment: Are you confusing "sybase anywhere" with SQL Anywhere? analytical functions (first link) should be in both; though, I admit, my knowledge of SYBASE is limited.  Still, the author never stated if he was using ASE or SA

Comment: Sybase IQ is not Sybase ASE... sybase stuff is so messed up, the OP says Sybase 12 (that's ASE)

Answer (score 0):

if you can add `seq_id` column to that table that started from 0 for each user_id. You can query with this column.

Comment: @stu: Can you add another table (keyed on combination of user_id and row_id of your existing table) with a seq_id on it? Unless you can add some kind of data somewhere you are out of luck on this, because your database design is inadequate for what you need to do.

Comment: well that kinda sucks. changing these tables (there's a bunch of them) would involve fixing lots of legacy applications which is why it's not really an option just for my piddly little project.
The only thing I came up with was to make a select from select type of thing where I did select top 3 then outside of that do a select top 1 with the order reversed. Extremely ugly but it will work. I was hoping for something simpler.
It would go like this:
select field from (select top 1 field from (select top 3 field from table) order by field) order by field desc